# I want to add a loading screen until the other component gets loaded after submitting the form in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to learn react. I am submitting a form. I have used `handleSubmit`. I want to add a loading screen until the other component gets loaded after submitting the form. How I can do that?

I have a `Detail` component and a `Summary` component.On submit it will go in either of the components.

In App.js,

```
handleSubmit(evt) {

   let prevState = this.initialState
    this.setState( prevState=> ({
        disabled: !prevState,
        }),
    );

    if (this.state.checkIds && this.state.checkIds.length > 0) {
        redirect = redirect.concat(`checkids=${this.state.checkIds}&`)
    }

    return this.props.history.push(redirect)

}
onClick = () => {
  this.setState(this.initialState)
    this.props.history.push("/");
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <form  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>
                Project ID:
                <input type="text" value={this.state.projectId} name="projectId" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </label>
            <button type="button"  class ="button" value="detail"  onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Detail</button>
            <button type="button" class ="button" value="summary" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Summary</button>
            <button type="button" class ="button" value="back"  disabled={this.state.disabled} onClick={this.onClick}>Back</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I want a loading page which will appear on clicking the button. It will be there until one of the components gets loaded

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear from your example code, but your state should have a `isLoading` and `hasLoaded` parameter. When you handle the submit, setState `isLoading: true`. When the loading is done, setState `isLoading: false` and `hasLoaded: true`. Then in your render you can do something like this:

```
render() {
  const {isLoading, hasLoaded} = this.state;
  return isLoading ? <Loader /> : hasLoaded ? <LoadedComponent /> : <FormWithButtonComponent />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, on your `state`, create a property named `loading: false`. Then create a component named `Spinner` which includes 2 files, `Spinner.js` and `Spinner.css`.

For the css, visit [this site](https://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/) and choose any spinner you want. Copy the `CSS` codes into your `Spinner.css`. Make sure change the `.load` class name with `.Loader`.

Then in your `Spinner.js` component, put this code:

```
import React from 'react';

import classes from './Spinner.css';

const spinner = () => (
    <div className={classes.Loader}>Loading...</div>
);

export default spinner;
```

After created your spinner component, Create an if statement in your `render()` to the component you wanna add spinner and in your `handleSubmit` function, handle the `loading` like this:

```
handleSubmit() {
    this.setState( {loading: true} );

    ...
    // after you completed your goal, add this
    this.setState( {loading: false} );
}

let button =<button type="button" class ="button" value="detail" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Detail</button>

 if (this.state.loading) {
     button = <Spinner />
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a mistake, `let yourComponentName` and the state check are defined where?

Comment: `let yourComponentName` can be defined as anything user wants. It can be the button he refers the `onClick` function. But it needs to declare to variable in order to use `if` statement. Then in `if` statement, he will check the state. I editted my answer to understand better.